# Юнит-тесты über alles

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Похоже, что метка [юнит-тесты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8e%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8b)  [одержала убедительную победу](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1320/181472).

Предлагаю синонимизировать к ней следующие три:

- [unit-testing](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unit-testing)
- [unittest](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unittest)
- [модульные-тесты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8b)

Метка новая, создана в общем русле русификации меток. Краткое и полное описание уже есть. Вчера расставил эту метку на всех вопросах про юнит-тесты, не отмеченных никакой меткой, так что сегодня у нас есть [12 голосующих участников](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D1%8E%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B/topusers). Этого достаточно для голосования. Чтобы добавить синонимы, проголосуйте за них:

> >> **[проголосуйте за синоним здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D1%8E%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B/synonyms)** <<

Если у вас есть ответы по англоязычным меткам, но нет по русскоязычной и баллов не хватает — переставьте метку на вопросах, на которые дали ответ. Ровно в полночь по серверному <s>карета</s> баллы пересчитаются.

Если у вас нет ответов, но вы хотите принять участие в голосовании — срочно напишите хороший ответ )