# Юнит-тесты или модульные тесты?

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Хочу перевести и синонимизировать метки [unit-testing](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unit-testing), [unittest](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unittest) и все остальные, связанные с модульным тестированием / юнит-тестированием к одной русскоязычной метке.

В данный момент подготовил краткое и полное описание для [юнит-тесты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8e%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8b), но ещё не поздно передумать. Поэтому давайте выберем одну метку, чтобы всех отыскать, воедино собрать и единым ключом в базе данных сковать.

## Центральной меткой должна стать:

Comment: Основная проблема тут в том, что не взирая на [Википедию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) часть программистов (и я в т.ч.) считают, что это разные виды тестов. / Может лучше соединить во что-нибудь более обобщенное? Что-то вроде *тесты-кода*

Comment: @avp интересно, можете рассказать, чем они отличаются? Может, мы две метки заведем?

Comment: Полазил по интернету и обнаружил, что сейчас во всех статьях  модули, компоненты и unit это практически одно и то же. Так что, пожалуй не надо мне никого путать, проще самому перестроиться. А вот как сейчас называют то, что я всегда считал модулем -- не знаю. (и ведь вопрос-то такой нынче не задать -- явный offtopic)

Comment: @avp: я думаю, что не оффтопик.

Comment: Ok. Если в самом деле интересно, на днях (вс. или пн.) набью вопрос с ответом (своим видением этой темы) на ru.SO

Comment: @avp конечно, мне фундаментальные вопросы всегда интересны.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**[юнит-тесты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8e%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8b)**

Это общеупотребимое название таких тестов в русскоязычной среде разработчиков. На русскоязычном SO гораздо больше результатов по юнит-тестам, чем по модульным тестам.

Comment: Я за этот вариант, т.к. эту метку пользователь сайта поймёт быстрее всего. (А цель метки — дать понять, о чём вопрос).

Comment: Только такое название противоречит нашему словарику(( https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1268

Answer (score 4):

**[модульные-тесты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8b)**

Это более верное с точки зрения русского языка название. Например, его использует Википедия.

Answer (score 2):

**[юнит-тестирование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8e%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)**

То же, что и с модульным.

Comment: Посмотрел на so.En и там по тегам такой результат: `unit-testing  x46710` `testing x26303`. Голосую за этот вариант. Хотя конечно, если делать акцент на перевод, то «модульное-тестирование» больше подходит. Но ведь все-равно мы там и там (so.En-so.Ru) обитаем и хочется больше унифицировать. И так, я за **unit-testing**.

Comment: @adamshakhabov сравнивать по популярности и выбирать между [tag:testing] и [tag:unit-testing] некорректно, т.к. это целое и его часть. Не всё тестирование — юнит-тестирование.

Answer (score 0):

**[модульное-тестирование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)**

Тестирование — это немного более широкая тема, чем тесты.

Answer (score -1):

Если бы процесс был изобретен в русскоязычной среде то, возможно, он бы назывался:

[проверка-модулей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9) или [проверка-блоков](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2)

Comment: Если уж совсем отказываться от заимствованных слов, то проверка частей или проверка самостоятельных единиц.

Comment: К первому апреля, кстати, можно весь Ru.SO перевести на такой язык, который сформировался бы, если СССР доминировал в информационных технологиях.

Comment: Кстати, ещё есть вариант [tag:испытания]. Он довольно хорошо соответствует тестированию в смысле промышленного производства.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, тут уже по моему сарказмом подпахивает :).